# Primitive of a meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I found this statement that I cannot justify due to my lack of knowledge in complex analysis (this is not my field of study).

Let $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ be the open unitary disc centered at $0$, let $f$ be a meromorphic function on $D$ with $0$ as the only pole. Then $f$ does not have a global primitive on $D\setminus \{0\}$.

I know some examples, but I would like to see a general proof. It would be great if your argument applies to the case of several variables i.e. $D\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ and $f:D\setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

In the $n=1$ case my intuition is that if $f$ has a global primitive than $1/z$ would have one, leading to a contradiction. But I cannot put this in a precise argument.

**Edit:** As pointed out by the answers, what stated before is false, being $1/z^2$ a counterexample. So I will quote the text, then you can tell me what I misunderstood.

> Take as $D$ an open disc in the complex plane centered around $0$, of
>   radius $1 < R \leq \infty $, with the point $0$ removed. We choose $1$ as base point for the
>   fundamental group of $D$. We study the local system of solutions of the first order
>   differental equation $$y' = f y$$ where $f$ is a holomorphic function on $D$ that extends meromorphically into $0$. It
>   is well known that the solutions to this equation in some neighbourhood of a point $x \in D$ are constant multiples of functions of the form $\text{exp} \circ F$ where $F$ is a primitive of $f$. Thus the solution sheaf is a locally constant sheaf of $1$-dimensional complex vector spaces. The reason why it is locally constant but not constant is that, as we learn
>   from complex analysis, the primitive $F$ exists locally but not globally on the whole of $D$.

Answer (score 3):

Of course $1/z^2$ is a counterexample. What's true is that if the residue at $0$ is non-zero *then* there is no primitive. Proof: Say $\gamma$ is the circle $|z|=1$. Then $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz\ne0$. On the other hand if $F$ is holomorphic in the punctured disk then $\int_\gamma F'(z)\,dz=0$. So $F'\ne f$.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't $\frac{1}{z}$ a primitive for $\frac{-1}{z^2}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not true that if $f$ has a single pole at $0$ then $f$ doesn't have a primitive in $D\setminus \{0\}.$ For example, if $f(z) = 1/z^2,$ then a primitive would be $-1/z.$

You're right that $f(z)=1/z$ doesn't have a primitive in $D\setminus \{0\}.$ To show this, let $D_1 = D\setminus (-1,0].$ Then the principal value $\log z$ is a primitive for $f$ in $D_1.$ If $f$ had a primitive $F$ in $D\setminus \{0\},$ then $(F(z)-\log z)'= 0$  in $D_1.$ Hence $F(z)-\log z$ is constant in $D_1.$ Since $\log z$ has "jump discontinuities" at every point of $(-1,0),$ the same must be true of $F,$ contradiction.